# Как выбрать все элементы с позиции N

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

Есть меню:

```
<li>Menu 1</li>
<li>Menu 2</li>
<li>Menu 3</li>
<li>Menu 4</li>
```

Мне нужно выбрать все элементы начиная с третьего, т.е. нужны:

```
<li>Menu 3</li>
<li>Menu 4</li>
```

Знаю что есть селектор `nth-child`, но я не разобрался как с помощью него можно выбрать несколько элементов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Документация по `nth-child`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child)

```css
li:nth-child(n + 3) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<li>Menu 1</li>
<li>Menu 2</li>
<li>Menu 3</li>
<li>Menu 4</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
li:nth-child(3) ~ li {
  color: red;
}
```